# what best way to handle forms with a big amount of fields?

Tags: php, data-structures

I am making some forms for a project and I have a big doubt if I am using the best data-structure posible, the problem is that I have to put some forms, each one has between 150-230 fields, each one is different, and has the options for the user selects, writes or uploads a file, once checked all fields requiered are filled I have to save on my DB, still its taking me too much time checking all the fields in my submit file (I am using PHP) and then save it in my DB.

Is there any good way to use a kind of array or something better or more robust for this form??

Thanks

Comment: you are expecting a user to fill in 150 to 230 fields?? this should be broken down at least in to a dozen+ pages.

Comment: Why in the world does your form have 230 fields?

Comment: I agree with @Dagon , you should break the fields up into multiple pages. Each page should have similar information requests. You could use cookies to keep track of the session and previous form entries

Comment: gee.. I know... its a HUGE form... but its requiered like that, its for get the details and pieces for constructions...

Comment: Then break it up. I'd be pissed if I was on form field #229 and hit refresh or lost my work somehow.

Comment: and let people come back to do more filling latter, obviously this could take many hours to fill in so don't make me do it all at once.

Comment: Perhaps one page for roofing, another for wall coverings, foundation, and load-bearing material? Just a suggestion on how to break it up into multiple pages

Comment: thanks @Dagon and awashburn , but the problem is not that, its in the way I have to process all the information, I dont want to make a request[field] or post per each one...

Comment: once you add a log in system, you could submit each answer as they add it via ajax

Comment: It's taking too much time to iterate over 230 fields in an array? I highly doubt that. What kind of validation are you applying? Also, as others mentioned, this form size is just horrendous; at least use sessions to keep whatever data they've entered so far and divide into pages.

Comment: If you don't make the field - then it wont exist, so ? if you have the fields in a db you can use then to generate the from, but you still have to create the structure first. i use a form builder class that takes question name,type, description etc to create the form.

Comment: I am using validation in jQuery firstly, and later with my framework (codeigniter), and there is the problem, I have to set the rules per each form (are about 14 forms), Id like to iterate each field.... but , how? I was thinking to create objects maybe... but I dont know :-s

Comment: re-scope the question, as all the comment show; it's to broad to be answerable.

Comment: Giving us more structure to the nature of your forms; such as form quantity and size, along with the quantity of their field types, would allow us to give you a more meaningful and specific aawnser.

Comment: for example, there is a section for the part "top" in that section I have to specify sizes, colors, position, structure,maps(images) and material of a "part", and there is part A, part B , part C ... so, basically they share same requirements, but I they can be different... some others dont share any field

Comment: I have never worked with so many fields in a form, but I would use jQuery to validate the form, I suggest you use a jQuery plugin called [Ketchup](http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/), I have used it and it is really helpful. Then try to split the form in various screens, like a wizard. Then, use the new technologies in html5 to save the data to the user's browser, so you can load the existing data if the user doesn't finish filling all the forms. Then use jQuery to send the information to PHP using ajax.